# Calculate variance and expected value

Tags: statistics

I am trying to do some combinations when calculating variance and expected value, but i am stuck, i dont know how to combine them.

the two functions look like this:

[image]

i calculate the variance for the first function to 0,3375 and expected value 2,25.

for the second function i get expected values 0,33 and 0,66 and the variances 5/36 and 17/36

but i dont know how to continue to solve the functions expected value and variance since they are two equations in one function, how do i combine them?

my last question is how do i calculate 5ξ + 12η ?

Comment: Does $(1+3\text{*}2+2)$ mean $9$ or something else?

Comment: (1) Integrate over separate intervals. Maybe, start with something simpler: $f(x) = k$ for $0 < x < 1$ and $f(x) = 2k$ for $1 < x < 2.$ Draw a sketch. (2) When you get means of random variables $\xi$ and $\eta$, of course, you have $E(5\xi + 12\eta) = 5E(\xi) + 3E(\eta).$ (3) Please answer @Henry's question.

Comment: yes it means 9.